# Why does this compiler message IDE0059 get generated for my ref param? It seems to me the message is unfounded, because it's a ref variable

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, ref, .net-standard-2.0

I've attempted to boil down my issue to the code below. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Community x64 v17.5.4. My .NET Framework is 4.8.04084.

This code is being compiled to target **net standard ** output.

```
public class MyClassA
{
    public static void DoWithFlagSet(Action action, ref bool flag, bool tempValue = true)
    {
        bool oldValue = flag;

                          //
        flag = tempValue; // THIS line generates IDE0059 message Unnecessary assignment
                          //   of a value to 'flag'

        try
        {
            action();
        }
        finally
        {
            flag = oldValue;
        }
    }

    protected bool ignoreChildEvents = default;
    protected virtual bool OptionA => true;
    protected virtual bool OptionB => false;

    protected virtual bool SomeSubroutine() =>
        ignoreChildEvents
            ? OptionA
            : OptionB;

    public void MakeSomeChanges()
    {
        bool result;
        DoWithFlagSet(() => result = SomeSubroutine(), ref ignoreChildEvents);
    }
}
```

I've tried refactoring but the compiler message keeps appearing. Is this a bug in VS?

Comment: Hah. I suspect this is a problem with the warning, yes: it isn't considering that the method could have side-effects which end up reading the field which is passed as `ref`. Here's a case which doesn't even need delegates: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK7wCYgNQB8ACATAIwCwAUBTAKYDuABACrUDOCAFAJQB0AglwG4KFIk1YIKAbwr1Z9AA7IoANwgJq9YAHstAG01Dyc+jLn4AzPXwAWev06nZ0o8bkAhdsmoAzTZ0PGAL6OJi6yFla2Hl6+2nr06mwOYfTOrnKJCPQAvAlo1AHp9ADCgiHGmTn03hC6LAUhwSkhETYlXCFpRfjEAJzswP6NFIFAA===

Comment: Interestingly, it only pops up on the "main" branch in SharpLab, and not "x64"